# How to proof the Fano's inequality using the following formulation?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, information-theory, entropy

The Fano's inequality for the Markov chain $X\to Y\to \hat{X}$ is given as follows $$H(X|\hat{X})\leq H(E)+P(E)\log_2(|\chi|),$$ where $E$ is error random variable defined such that $E=1$ if $X\neq \hat{X}$ and $E=0$ if $X=\hat{X}$. Further, $\chi$ is the set of values which $X$ can take and $|\chi|$ is the number of elements in $\chi$.

My Try:

I am using the approach devised in the book "Elements of Information Theory" and for that I have to show that $$H(X|E,\hat{X})\leq P(E)\log_2(|\chi|).~~~~~(1)$$ According to the definition of entropy I can write $$H(X|E,\hat{X})=-\sum_{X}\sum_{E}\sum_{\hat{X}}p(X,E,\hat{X})\log_2(p(X|E,\hat{X})).$$ Which can be further written as follows $$H(X|E,\hat{X})=-\sum_{X}\sum_{\hat{X}}p(X,E=0,\hat{X})\log_2(p(X|E=0,\hat{X}))-\sum_{X}\sum_{\hat{X}}p(X,E=1,\hat{X})\log_2(p(X|E=1,\hat{X})).$$ I know that the first part of the above equation is zero but I do not understand how the second part is equal to $$P(E=1)H(X|\hat{X},E=1).$$ I need help in understanding this part. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typesetting comment: you should use `\mathcal{X}` to typeset $\mathcal{X}$, not `\chi`.

---

By definition,
$$H(X \mid \hat{X}, E=1) = - \sum_X \sum_{\hat{X}} p(X, \hat{X} \mid E=1) \log_2 (p(X \mid \hat{X}, E=1)).$$
Multiplying both sides by $P(E=1)$.

Comment: Thank you for answering.